From algebra to analysis using the scalar product
Consider a (linear) tensor space, with introduced metric tensors, i.e. bilinear symmetric positive definite (semidefinite) tensors of the second order $g$, $\widehat g$. (I'm actually working with exterior algebra on a (pseudo) scalar product space, but that doesn't change anything).
I want to transition from algebra to analysis as naturally (and simply) as possible to introduce tangent vectors and tangent space.
The closest to what I want that I have come across is Munkres (Analysis on Manifolds). Which starts from the metric and the metric space, defines the $\epsilon$-neighborhood and then the open set->open ball->continuity introduced by the metric->limit->derivative ...
I can simply use the scalar product, or of a positive definite metric tensor, define a norm, work with a metric vector space, and assume a norm-induced metric (and a metric-induced topology)? So, to perform the Munkres procedure from $\epsilon$-neighborhoods to the derivation using the norm, of course with much less demand for generality?
Do you know of an equally accessible author like Munkres who induces topology from a normed vector space?
Are there any limits to this approach when it comes to the continuity of some functions in conjunction with the Riemann integral? Thanks
